# How do I iterate over an array of hashes and count the duplicate results in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes called cleanconnections

```
[{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}]
```

I want to be able to group together the similar arrays in cleanconnections and end up with a count inside the array, such as:

```
[{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567", :count=>3},
{:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321", :count=>1}]
```

I have tried:

```
count = { }
cleanconnections.map { |name,number| 
    namenumber = name.zip(number)
    count[{namenumber => count += 1}]
}
```

But this results in:

```
TypeError: wrong argument type NilClass (must respond to :each)
        from (irb):2367:in `zip'
        from (irb):2367:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):2365:in `map'
        from (irb):2365
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

as well as trying:

```
cleanconnections.each {|x| 
    x.store(x, count[x] +1 )
}
```

But this results in:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):2376:in `block in irb_binding'
        from (irb):2375:in `each'
        from (irb):2375
        from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I have tried putting both of these in an

```
unless x.nil?
```

But that did not change the errors.

As you can probably tell, I am very new to ruby. Can anyone please help pointing me in the right direction? I appreciate it! Also, first post on stackoverflow, so feedback is also appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) I'd write an answer, but it seems that someone with a better explanation and code already answered it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236656/how-to-count-duplicates-hash-itens-in-ruby-1-8-5-sketchup-ruby-api

Comment: Thank you very much! Your searching abilities are far superior to mine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been answered before, but there is always room for improvement:

```
a = [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
     {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"},
     {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321"},
     {:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567"}]

a.group_by{|h|h}.map{|k,v|k[:count]=v.size;k}
# => [{:name=>"John Doe1", :number=>"5551234567", :count=>3},
#     {:name=>"John Doe2", :number=>"5557654321", :count=>1}]
```

Comment: Or `a.uniq.map { |h| {name: h[:name], number: h[:number], count: a.count(h)} }`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes...`a.uniq.map { |h| h[count: a.count(h)];h }` is enough. But it takes much time than this one, so I didn't post it last night.